# What Linux commands can parse a file with two delimiters per line?

Tags: linux, awk, nested

I've got a file that contains two delimiters ("**:**" and "**,**"), and I basically want something like a nested/recursive AWK command that will let me iterate over the values I want:

```
Value-1.1:Value-1.2:Value-1.3:Value-1.A,Value-1.B,Value-1.C
Value-2.1:Value-2.2:Value-2.3:Value-2.A,Value-2.B
```

For every Value-1.{A|B|C} I want to do something with Value-1.2, and then move on to the next line, where for every Value-2.{A|B}, I want to do something with Value-2.2, and so on.

Is this something I can do in a single AWK script, or am I going to need to be creative with pipes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk uses a regular expression to indicate the field separator. E.g.,

```
awk -F ':|,' '{ print NF }'
```

will show

```
6
5
```

for your input lines.

Answer (score 0):

an example with perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
  my @vals = split(/,|:/, $line);
  for (my $value) (@vals) {
    print $value, "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get creative with awk by replacing the field separator and assigning to `$0`:

```
 v11 = $1;
 v12 = $2;
 FS = ",";
 $0 = $3;
 print v11 " " v12 " " $1;
```